# Where to place negation ('ne' + 'plus') in a sentence?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, négation, ordre-des-mots

Why is *ne* + *plus* wrapped around *as* instead of *besoin* in the following sentence:

> Tu n'as plus besoin de ta voiture.

Shouldn't it be wrapped around *besoin* as that is the verb word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Besoin* is a noun. The verb is *as* (from the verb *avoir*). *Avoir besoin* is a phrasal verb (literally “to have need”), which determines its meaning, but does not change the grammar. Even if *besoin* was a verb form, the second negation word would still be after the auxiliary:

> Tu ne manges pas tes carottes.
>   Tu n'a pas mangé tes carottes.

Comment: The first part of the answer (i.e. besoin being a noun) automatically means that the negation goes around 'as', and so my question is answered, but I don't get why the term auxiliary was used as I my sentence didn't contain any compound tenses so I am confused as to why this term (and the examples given) were used.

Comment: Gilles is giving the general rule of the place of the negation when *avoir* is used, whether as verb or an auxiliary.

Comment: @user2966 Even if you weren't sure whether you had a verb and a complement or an auxiliary verb and a main verb, the negation would still be in the same place.